# VBA paste formulas from filtered column

Tags: excel, vba, formula

is there way in Excel(VBA) to copy/paste formulas from filtered column in 1 statement ? This works :

```
Sheets(1).Range("A2:C" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets(2).Range("A2:C" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

But this returns messed up rows (probably because column is filtered) :

```
Sheets(2).Range("A2:C" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = Sheets(1).Range("A2:C" & LastRow).Formula
```

any ideas if it's possible to do it without using clipboard, in 1 statement ?

**EDIT**

In Sheet1, I add formulas to columns A,B and C:

```
With Sheets(1)
    LastRow = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:A" & LastRow).Value = "=D5/$A$3*100"
    .Range("A:AG").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=">=1/1/2014", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=12/31/2014"
    .Range("B5:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "=D" & .UsedRange.Offset(5, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row & "/$B$3*100"
    .Range("A:AG").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=">=1/1/2015"
    .Range("C5:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "=D" & .UsedRange.Offset(5, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row & "/$C$3*100"
    .ShowAllData
End With
```

Therefore column A has formula "=Dn/$A$3*100, where n is row number. B and C formulas have division by B3 and C3 cell value. Then I filter Sheet1, copy filtered rows and paste them to Sheet2

```
Sheets(1).Range("A4:AG" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=name
Sheets(1).Range("A5:C" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets(2).Range("A5:C" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Comment: Have you tried with `.FormulaLocal` rather than `.Formula`? There is also `.FormulaHidden` and `.FormulaArray` that might be helpful.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, correct values only before first excluded row by filter. thank for suggestion anyway

Comment: Maybe there is something to dig with `Enum XlCellType`, containing : `Const xlCellTypeFormulas = -4123 (&HFFFFEFE5)
` and `Const xlCellTypeVisible = 12`

Comment: Can you add a picture of an example of the formula?  Which sheet is filtered?  The copy side or the paste side? Beware that `.End` will skip hidden cells which becomes relevant when you have filtered data.  Can you also show where `LastRow` comes from?  I bumped your rep past 10, so you can post a picture.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but bringing the formula to another worksheet presents problems. The formula can be picked up in a loop but needs to have the cell addresses modified to reflect the original worksheet name. If the [Application.ConvertFormula method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822751.aspx) is applied and the formula is converted to a strictly *xlAbsolute* style, then each *$* could be examined to see if prefacing with the original worksheet name is appropriate. The formula you've supplied (e.g. =D*n*/$A$3*100) is fairly straightforward and shouldn't present any problems parsing out.

```
Sub Copy_Filtered_Formulas()
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, rVIS As Range
    Dim vr As Long, vc As Long, sFRML As String, p As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws2
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(5, 1)) Then
            With .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
                .Resize(.Rows.Count, 3).ClearContents
            End With
        End If
    End With

    With ws1
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        lc = .Range("AG:AG").Column
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Cells(4, 1).Resize(lr - 3, lc)
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 3)
                .Formula = "=$D5/A$3*100"
            End With
            .AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=0
            With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 3)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    For Each rVIS In Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
                        sFRML = Application.ConvertFormula(rVIS.FormulaR1C1, xlR1C1, xlA1, xlAbsolute, rVIS)
                        p = InStr(1, sFRML, Chr(36))
                        Do While CBool(p)
                            If Asc(Mid(sFRML, p + 1, 1)) >= 65 And _
                              Asc(Mid(sFRML, p + 1, 1)) <= 90 And _
                              Asc(Mid(sFRML, p - 1, 1)) <> 33 And _
                              Asc(Mid(sFRML, p - 1, 1)) <> 58 Then
                                sFRML = Left(sFRML, p - 1) & Chr(39) & .Parent.Name & Chr(39) & Chr(33) & Mid(sFRML, p, 999)
                                p = InStr(p + Len(.Parent.Name) + 5, sFRML, Chr(36))
                            Else
                                p = InStr(p + 3, sFRML, Chr(36))
                            End If
                        Loop
                        With ws2
                            .Cells(Rows.Count, rVIS.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula = sFRML
                        End With
                    Next rVIS
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Of course, if you had never intended to transfer the original worksheet's name along with the formula then a lot of the code can be discarded.